# Port: command not found, even though /.bash_profile is 'correct'

Tags: macports, bash

I've recently installed Macports, to eventually, install the INTL extension on my MAMP. I'm currently trying to update the Macports -

```
sudo port -v selfupdate
```

which returns the error -

> sudo: port: command not found

I've read that it could be the paths in the .bash_profile. These are my paths:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin

export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/opt/local/share/man

export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/opt/local/share/info
```

From here, I'm not really sure on how to diagnose further. If you require any further files, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't started a new shell or otherwise `source`d your `.bash_profile`, the change to `PATH` isn't present in the value of `PATH` used by the current shell.

Comment: I have sourced my .bash_profile but it still isn't picking the paths up for my Composer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the .bash_profile file. Use the .profile file was created from macport. This will work.

Cheers,

Marco